# Fortran double summation

Tags: sum, fortran

So, I want to do a double summation over two variables of a four-variable function, my question is: are the summations in the picture equivalent? Am I doing it right?

[image]

Comment: does Fortran have indentation? And [do not post code in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Welcome. The code must be entered as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not think you are doing that right.  Your two sums are going to be identical.

Try this:

```
  do i=1,s
     do j=1,s
        prob1(i,j)=sum(prob(i,j,:,:))
        prob2(i,j)=sum(prob(:,:,i,j))
     end do
  end do
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Now I have another problem, I'm not being able to use the command "sum" in my program, it keeps telling me "unexpected array reference" (not recognizing the command), which is weird because whenever I create a new program, the command works just fine... Would you have a solution that does not involve "sum"? Or could you help me identify why the command is not being recognized? Here is my full code, just in case http://textuploader.com/d9w8f

Comment: There are two problems, besides the loops.  First, `sum=0`, but `sum` is not defined.  (Just delete it.)  Then, your array summation is wrong.  You  have `prob(i,j)` on the right-hand-side, and it should be `prob1(i,j)`.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what options?

Comment: I use force 2.0 as fortran IDE... I don't know why but the command "sum" is working again, however the result is still wrong.

Comment: Here is the full fixed code: http://textuploader.com/d9bot . Honestly, now that I know the problem is not in the summation, I think there is a problem with the method I'm using rather than with the code, I'll check with my prof. Thank you very much for the help!